# Tooltip using 'xlink:title' works fine in Chrome but not in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, graphviz

So I have this line of code which generates SVG page with graphviz and .dot written in a perl file. Everything works as intended except this tooltip in IE.

This is the bit of code I have generating my branch and tooltip.

```
"this -- that [tooltip =\"Please work \" ]"
```

In chrome it works how intended and shows 'Please work' when I hover on it in IE 11 it resorts to a default tooltip.

When I inspect element in IE it looks something like this(this might help diagnose):

```
<g class="node" id="node13">
  <title> IE Tooltip </title>

  <g id="a_node13">
    <a xlink:title="Please work">
```

Can I force it to use the child title and not resort to the deault 'IE Tooltip' title or another work around?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciate, I'll keep an eye on any questions

Thanks in advance.